# onclick() does not work in a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, onclick

i created an appointments table and added two links to accept and reject appointments. the links are displayed in every row of the table but when **i click it the text accept & reject are only displayed in the first row & I also need to know how to insert the text that appears after  the button click into the db** i would request someone to pls provide me some help thanks!

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php" >
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>appoinment ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>teacher</th>
            <th>parent</th>
            <th> accept/reject </th>
            <th>label</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php 
            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `app` left join `par` on par.par_id=app.par_id
            left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id
            ORDER BY app_id DESC");

                if($query === false)
                {
                    throw new Exception(mysql_error($conn));
                }
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $ann_id=$row['app_id'];
                    $date=$row['date'];
                    $msg=$row['time'];

                    $username = $row['username'];
                     $username = $row['p_username'];
            ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['app_id'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo date('j/m/y',strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['time'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
            <td>    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='reject';">reject</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
               <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='accept';">accept</a>&nbsp;  &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
               <div id="chgtext">PENDING</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <?php 
            }

            ?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to use `this` keyword - do some reading about that. In jQuery it would be `$(this).closest('tr').find('#chgtext').innerHTML='accept';` It finds the tr the a clicked is in, then finds chgtext inside of that row

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek i didnt understand

Comment: your loop `while` will create several id `chgtext`, it's not good w3c pratice

Comment: @Fky then how to do it

Comment: The problem is you do not tell JavaScript which `#chgtext` you mean (BTW it should be a class, not an id). If you use  `document.getElementById('chgtext')` you say "find #chgtext and select it". And that is precisely what js does. Finds the first one and selects it. There is however, a keyword `this` that refers to object you clicked. You can use it as a base to find the right #chgtext

Comment: I can make you a snippet, but I can only do it in jQuery to be honest

Comment: An `id` should be unique. Increase your `id` in `while` loop.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek okay then how to do it through jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery it would look like this:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="reject">reject</a> 
    <a href="#" class="accept">accept</a>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="chgtext">PENDING</div>
</td>
```

Then, before closing body tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.reject').on('click', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest('tr'); //find the row the link is in
            var thediv = row.find('.chgtext') //find the correct div within that tr
            $(thediv).text('reject');
        });
        $('.accept').on('click', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest('tr'); //find the row the link is in
            var thediv = row.find('.chgtext') //find the correct div within that tr
            $(thediv).text('accept');
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can make the code shorter, but I wanted to show you how it works step by step.

Comment: should i add anything additionally to this code...currently doesnt work

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: NO... can u explain

Comment: between the head tags of your page you need to include jquery: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Also, there was a bug in my script, I corrected it

Comment: thanks bro it works...what should i do to insert it into the db

Comment: That is a whole another question and you should try it yourself first. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: `<?php   
  if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id'])) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET state = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['state'], $_GET['s.app_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}    }`  **i added this code in order to update the accept/reject in the db but it doesnt work can u help**

Comment: You should post a new question, it will be hard to write a readable code in the comments